# Display the network connection 2g/3g or 4g in a toast

Tags: networking, connection, toast, 3g, 4g

I would like to display in a toast which network connection is available. 
But when I start my app it shows me the layout, but it doesn't make a toast.
Did I forget something?

// Now i shows every second a toast. it beginns with the right one but then it goes to the next one..
I also have a button now, which shows me the networktyp in a textview. But it always just show the 4g..
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Button start;
TextView ergebniss;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);

    ergebniss = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

}


public void getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    switch (networkType) {

    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2G", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ergebniss.setText("2G");


    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3G", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ergebniss.setText("3G");


    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4G", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ergebniss.setText("4G");


    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getNetworkClass(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least show the Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2G", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And you're missing a `break;` (or return ..) statement after the `Toast.makeText()` calls.

Comment: Then where/when are you calling the getNetworkClass() method ?